# PyQt5 change app theme/palette dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I can successfully create a new palette and set it to the QApplication at launch. However, once the application is running, I cannot change the colors of the palette anymore. I would like to change the colors of the buttons if the user chooses a particular theme. The current code which works at launch but not later is as follows:

```
palette = QtGui.QPalette()
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QColor(3, 18, 14))
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QtGui.QColor(15, 15, 15))
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, QtGui.QColor(53, 53, 53))
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, QtCore.Qt.white)
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, QtCore.Qt.white)
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Button, QtGui.QColor(53, 53, 53))
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, QtCore.Qt.white)
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, QtCore.Qt.red)
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, QtGui.QColor(142, 45, 197).lighter())
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, QtCore.Qt.black)
app.setPalette(palette)
```

The same palette object if used in a slot doesnt change the color. Eg code in the slot:

```
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Button, QtGui.QColor(53, 53, 53))
app.setPalette(palette)
```

Could someone please let me know what I am missing here?
Thanks.

Edit:
I just found out that it modified only some of the areas. For eg, in the slot I have written, it changes the highlight color, but not the QTab color (which was set by setting color to Button). My current slot code:

```
def change_theme(self): 
    pal = QtWidgets.QApplication.palette() 
    #The next line works 
    pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 128)) 
    #The next line doesnt work. Expected it to change the Tab Widget color 
    #using this line. 
    pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Button, QtGui.QColor(62, 80, 91)) 
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setPalette(pal)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `app.setStyle('Fusion')`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette, QColor

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flag = False

        self.button = QPushButton('change the colors of the buttons', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.click)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)

        self.palette = self.palette()
        self.palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(3, 18, 14))

        self.palette.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor('red'))  

        self.setPalette(self.palette)

    def click(self):
        print("click")
        if not self.flag:
            self.palette.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(62, 80, 91))
        else: 
            self.palette.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(0, 0, 128))

        self.setPalette(self.palette)
        self.flag = not self.flag


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication([])

    app.setStyle('Fusion')                              # <-----

    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain further as to why setting a 'style' to the app changes the behaviour of the 'palette' of the app ?